# Linq2Sql: Sum of joined column

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda

I need to Sum values in a column of a list of objects joined to the list I have.
For example, I have classes A and B, and B has a value I want to Sum:

```
class A
{
     //props
}

class B
{
    //props
    decimal ValToSum { get; set; }
}
```

A has a relation with B so that each A can have many Bs joined.

And I have a list of As from my data context:

```
IEnumerable<A> myList;
// obtain myList from DataContext
```

Now I want to sum ValToSum properties of every B resulting from the join with A.

Something like:

```
myList.Bs.Sum(x => x.ValToSum);
```

How can I access the list of all Bs related to As in myList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` to flatten the sequances into one and than use `Sum`

```
myList.SelectMany(x => x.Bs).Sum(x => x.ValToSum);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var sum = myList.SelectMany(i => i.Bs).Sum(i => i.ValToSum);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Upvoted, but not marked answered because of other correct answer from Magnus (faster and more commented). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = myList.Bs.Select(x => x.ValToSum).Sum();
```

Comment: I don't have Bs collection in myList. I have Bs collection in A (e.g A.Bs).